# How to keep a high score list tied with user?

Tags: java, sorting, file-io, user-input

In its simplest form, my game has a counter for a score, and I want that counter to be stored along with a user name that is inputted and sort them from highest to lowest. I would imagine I want to write both attributes to a text file and then when I ask for the leaderboard I can read the text file. How would I go about this?

Comment: Since you are only using a 2 data point collection I would create a class for the data a linked list for the collection and be able to use the standard library Collections sort functionality unless you are dealing with 10,000 plus players this should easily be able to handle what you need and not even take that much comp time to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

For structuring your data in memory, a `HashMap` would work well. A `Map` is a collection of key-value pairs. Use the username as the key and the score as the value. Sort the `HashMap` on the score.